# Какой метод заменит следующее логическое условие?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли записать это условие как-то по другому?

```
Double Ugol;
if (Ugol>360) Ugol = Ugol - 360;
```

Comment: Стандартная операция получения остатка при целочисленном делении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте операцию получения остатка, она работает и с `Double`.

```
Ugol = Ugol % 360;
```

Answer (score 1):

да. вот так

```
(Ugol>360)?Ugol%= 360;
```